# html5 applicationCache from disk cache

Tags: html, browser-cache

if i change manifest file then the ressources are loaded but only "from disk cache" so my modifications are not effected [image: chrome console]

(i can't ask to all users to empty chrome's cache)

Solutions?
thanks a lot
best regards